# Saving/updating ansible.log in SVN after every execution

Tags: svn, yaml, ansible

I have to find a solution, to save/update the ansible log file in the SVN after the completion of the script execution.

It should be like, as soon as the yml script completes its execution, whether it fails or passes, the file ansible.log (which saves the log locally) should get saved into the SVN automatically.

It should get saved if on the defined SVN path no log file is present, but if log file is present, it should delete the old log and replace it with the new log file.

I tried googling about it, but couldn't find any solution. Any links/pointer/way to solve the problem, in this direction will be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: This doesn't seem like an Ansible specific question, rather you want to save your logfile into SVN after Ansible exits.  Whatever method you're using to run the Ansible command, have the next command after it perform the expected SVN check-in and commit steps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use delegation to run the svn commands locally:

```
  - name: Commit logs
    command: /usr/local/bin/commit_ansible_logs.sh
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

This will trigger the commit_ansible_logs.sh bash script that YOU would need to write to commit the log.

See [delegation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) in the manual.

You can also "detatch" the command from ansible if you want put a delay or loop that watches for the ansible run to finish.

The second half of this article explains how to "fire and and forget" a task in an Ansible play.

[Fire and Forget using async article](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_async.html)